# [PHP]Curl preg_match_all extract the html tags

Tags: php, curl

I wrote the following PHP Code:

```
$postdata = 'username=userXXXX&password=passXXXX';

$ch = curl_init('website.com/user/login');  
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postdata);  
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 6.0; en-US)');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, "cookie.txt");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, "cookie.txt");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

    $string = curl_exec ($ch);  
    curl_close($ch);

    //print_r($string);
```

Sometimes when i reload the script like 6-7 times, i have to complete an Captcha.

What i need? I need to get the catpcha into my script to complet it manually if it will appear.

There are the HTML tags of the captcha:

```
<div class="content-bg-bottom">
            <h2>Security Code</h2>
            <div class="inner-form-border">
                <div class="inner-form-box">
                    <h3>Confirm the Login</h3>
                    <p>Please write the following captcha code for get into your account.</p>
                    <form name="captchaForm" id="captchaForm" action="http://website.com/captcha" method="post">
                                                    <div id="captchaContainer">
                            <script type="text/javascript">
/* <![CDATA[ */
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#reloadCaptcha').bind('click', function() {
        var d = new Date();
        $('#captchaImage').attr('src', 'http://website.com/captcha/create?' + d.getTime());
    });
});
/* ]]> */
```

```
                            <label for="answer">Security Code: *</label>
                            <input class="validate[required]" id="answer" name="answer" title="" value="" maxlength="10" type="text">
                        </div>
                        <input id="submitBtn" class="btn-big" name="SubmitCaptchaForm" value="Trimite" type="submit">
                        <script type="text/javascript">
                                                        </script>
                    </form>
                    <p id="regLegend">* obligatory fields</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: question is not clear, where is problem?

Comment: I'm sending PHP POST data, sometimes the username and the passwords are wrong, and if i send the same post data i have to complete the captcha code. Well, i send the post data from my localhost/script.php to website.com/login. I need to get the captcha into my script to complet it by myself.

Comment: You're trying to brute force some kind of password probably not yours, no help from me.